# Posting from JTextFields into array

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Ok So i have made my array and added an action listener so that when the button named "Submit" is clicked all data from my JTextFields should be entered into an ArrayList although this is not happening, any help on why not would be appreciated. below is the Action Listener action Performed.

```
public class Main {
    String HouseNumber, StreetName, Town, Postcode, Beds, Price, Type;
    JTextField HouseNumber1, StreetName1, Town1, Postcode1, Beds1, Price1,
            Type1;
    JLabel HouseNumberLabel, StreetNameLabel, TownLabel, PostcodeLabel,
            BedsLabel, PriceLabel, TypeLabel;
    JButton Submit;
    JPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main gui = new Main();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        HouseNumberLabel = new JLabel("House Number");
        HouseNumber1 = new JTextField("");
        StreetNameLabel = new JLabel("Street name");
        StreetName1 = new JTextField("");
        TownLabel = new JLabel("Town");
        Town1 = new JTextField("");
        PostcodeLabel = new JLabel("Postcode");
        Postcode1 = new JTextField("");
        BedsLabel = new JLabel("Number of beds");
        Beds1 = new JTextField("");
        PriceLabel = new JLabel("Price (£)");
        Price1 = new JTextField("");
        TypeLabel = new JLabel("Building Type");
        Type1 = new JTextField("");
        Submit = new JButton("Submit");
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add contents to JFrame and JPanel
        panel.add(HouseNumberLabel);
        panel.add(HouseNumber1);
        panel.add(StreetNameLabel);
        panel.add(StreetName1);
        panel.add(TownLabel);
        panel.add(Town1);
        panel.add(PostcodeLabel);
        panel.add(Postcode1);
        panel.add(BedsLabel);
        panel.add(Beds1);
        panel.add(PriceLabel);
        panel.add(Price1);
        panel.add(TypeLabel);
        panel.add(Type1);
        panel.add(Submit);
        frame.pack();
        frame.show();

        final ArrayList<Main> p = new ArrayList<Main>();
        Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Main array = new Main();
                HouseNumber = HouseNumber1.getText();
                StreetName = StreetName1.getText();
                Town = Town1.getText();
                Postcode = Postcode1.getText();
                p.add(array);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Using standard Java variable naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your Main class has the fields, since it's also managing the GUI, you don't want to create an `ArrayList<Main>`

If you just need to collect all the strings then you can create

```
ArrayList<String> houseDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

houseDetails.add(HouseNumber);
houseDetails.add(StreenName);
houseDetails.add(Town);
houseDetails.add(Postcode);
```

but the cleaner thing to do would be to create a class to manage these

```
class House
{
    private String houseNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String town;
    private String postcode;

    public String getHouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }
    public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }
    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }
    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }
    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }
}
```

and then create a House and set all the valuse.

```
final ArrayList<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();
```

and in your actionPerformed event

```
House house = new House();
house.setHouseNumber(HouseNumber);
...

houses.add(house);
```

Comment: What do you mean by settlers?

Comment: how does your `Main` class take these string ? there's got to be these `set` methods or just fields like `array.HouseNumber = HouseNumber;`

Comment: would it be any better if i could show you my whole code? im a little confused lol

Comment: yeah that would help. but if it's too much code (> 150 lines) then why don't you create a pastie from pastie.org and post the link in your question

Comment: i have editted the main post showing the all of the code from the class, id be very grateful if you could send me in the right direction so that the data is passed into the array list, Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for all the help, makes a whole lot more sense now.

Comment: i have just test this and although there are no errors the details still don't appear to be being passed anywhere, they are not shown in my code anywhere :S

Comment: just for the record: a really useful House would be observable, that is notify interested parties about changes ;-)